# find the next with jquery when no sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

After I enter the `maxlength` number of characters in an input I need to focus on  the next input. The issue is that the next input is not always a sibling:

```js
jQuery("input").on('input', function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length == jQuery(this).attr('maxlength')) {
    jQuery(this).next("input").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
When you have write 4 char, the focus have to switch to the next input:
<div>
  OK
  <input maxlength="4">
  <input maxlength="4">
</div>
KO
<input id="inputWithTheIssue">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `.next()` function since all the `inputs` are not siblings. So you need to find the `index` of the current input in the entire set of input controls and increment it by 1 to find the next occurring input element.

```
jQuery("input").on('input',function () {
            if(jQuery(this).val().length == jQuery(this).attr('maxlength')) {
              var currIndex = $(this).index();  // gets the index value w.r.t the other input controls
              $('input').eq(currIndex + 1).focus();
            }
        });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/uhpn7pyx/2/

Comment: Maybe an explanation could serve to help the OP and future readers

Comment: Will this throw an error when `currIndex + 1` doesn't return a jQuery object and then tries to call `focus()`?

Comment: No it won't. It would only throw an undefined error if you are trying to access it's attribute or property value. events are okay.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to do.

1. Add [type="text"] attribute to your elements.
2. Use a proper parent element to get the child inputs. (I am using document as parent which might not be favorable for your scenario.)

```js
var $check = $(document).find('input[type="text"]');
jQuery("input").on('input', function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length == jQuery(this).attr('maxlength')) {
    $check.eq($check.index(this) + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
When you have write 4 char, the focus have to switch to the next input:
<div>
  OK
  <input maxlength="4" type="text">
  <input maxlength="4" type="text">
</div>
KO
<input id="inputWithTheIssue" type="text">
```

Comment: input without type attributes are treated as text by default. So you don't need to declare it explicitly.

Comment: @DinoMyte But we won't be able to select them using this `input[type="text"]`.

Comment: It would only matter if the DOM has other input types. In the question OP asked, it's not needed.

Comment: @DinoMyte The question does not all the time be descriptive enough. There can be things OP has missed. There is nothing wrong with taking precaution.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly asking for a jQuery solution, but you can do it really easily in pure JavaScript, without the need to incorporate any library.

```js
function inputChanged(element, index, array) {
  element.oninput = function() {
    if (element.value.length >= 4 && (index < array.length - 1)) {
      array[index + 1].focus();
    }
  }
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(inputChanged);
```

```html
<div>
  <input maxlength="4"/>
  <input maxlength="4"/>
</div>
<input id="inputWithTheIssue"/>
```

What I do here is invoking `inputChanged` function for every `input` in your document. This function takes parameter:

- `element` which holds element that invoked it,
- `index` which holds information which `input` among all of them invoked this function, and
- `array` that stores all those `input`s.

Inside this function on user's input I check if:

- a given element has value of 4 or more, and
- if we are not at the last position among all of the `input`s.

If it is so, we are focusing the next element from an array.

Even if you wanted jQuery way to solve your problem, I hope you or maybe someone else too, will find this answer helpful.